# How to create number format in different language in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I have bullet list numbers in a different language?

For ex, I want to have numbers in Bengali. Which is like ১, ২, ৩, ৪, ...

I can see English, Roman, Arabic is supported. But I can't see how to make a custom number list.

Comment: Which version of word? 2010?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the document language to Bengali? (**Tools** -> **Language** -> **Set Language**?)

Comment: Yes, that does not help.

Answer (score -2):

1st install sutonnnymj fonts on your c drive. it should be in c drive>windows>fonts..just download the font and copy the fonts to the folder i mentioned. then open your word file and search sutonnymj on your font style. then type 1) ..it should be like ১) , if you r using Avro, i suggest u should avoid it and try Bijoy..then it should work..

Comment: Your answer seems to assume some prior knowledge. What is "sutonnnymj", "Avro" and "Bijoy"? And where is one supposed to get them?